# Cocoa How to remember the window position with multiple monitors?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nswindow

To save window position for one(main) monitor i'm using this code:

```
[[win windowController] setShouldCascadeWindows:NO]; 
[win setFrameAutosaveName:@"My App"];
```

It's works fine. 
But if I connect second monitor and drag my app window to second monitor, cocoa autosave  does not work - after restart, window always placed on primary(main) monitor.
Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Enable restore for your app:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@YES forKey:@"NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows"];
}
```

Set your window to be restorable in Interface Builder

Also make sure that you don't call  invalidate on close. It is just promise -> you might end app with deleted state

```
[self.window invalidateRestorableState];
```

To verify/debug check if the content of "~/Library/Saved Application State/yourbundleidentifier" persists after restart.